# Can I install virtualenv in a different version of python?

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.6, python-3.7

I have ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6.5, and python 3.7.

When I run:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 api_server
```

I get this:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.7
Using base prefix '/usr'
/home/kyle/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py:1041: DeprecationWarning:
the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's
documentation for alternative uses
```

I want to code in python3.7 but the package virtualenv is in python3.6. Can I continue to create virtual environments using virtualenv in my python3.6 directory or should I install it in python 3.7 too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *just a warning*. You can ignore it. `virtualenv` works just fine with Python 3.7.

In a *future* version of Python, the `imp` module *may* be gone. But that time has yet to come, and the `virtualenv` project will have updated their code before that point.

It's notable that the [`virtualenv` project has been aware of this issue since Python 3.4](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/955), and the `imp` module is *still around in 3.7*. There is no timeline set for the module being removed at this time, so there is no real hurry. The [original tracker entry](https://bugs.python.org/issue17177) that discusses the removal hints at removal in Python 4, but that's not really set in stone either.

Comment: So I will just continue on then. Thanks!